# Ido mode and recently opened files

Tags: emacs

I recently switched to `ido-mode` in emacs.

When I run `C-x C-f` (`ido-find-file`) pressing `M-r` to do a regex search in the recently used files doesn't work any more.

Is there a way to enable this regex search for recently used files in `ido-mode`, too?

Answer (score 2):

When you press `C-x C-f` again on the `ido-find-file` promt (`C-x C-f C-x C-f`) it should switch to the regular `find-file` promt and `M-r` works again.
This also helps with `ido-mode` interfering when you try to visit new files with names similar to existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing one more `C-f` (i.e., `C-xC-fC-f` in total) will take you back to the stock find-file prompt.